# How to free memory in try-catch blocks?

Tags: c++, try-catch, delete-operator

I have a simple question hopefully - how does one free memory which was allocated in the try block when the exception occurs? Consider the following code:

```
try
 {
  char *heap = new char [50];
        //let exception occur here
  delete[] heap;
 }
 catch (...)
 {
  cout << "Error, leaving function now";
  //delete[] heap; doesn't work of course, heap is unknown to compiler
  return 1;
 }
```

How can I free memory after the heap was allocated and exception occurred before calling `delete[] heap`? Is there a rule not to allocate memory on heap in these try .. catch blocks?

Comment: Why use new, when you can use smart pointers and RAII-friendly containers?

Comment: @Pavel - Smart pointers and RAII containers still have issues in complex usage, most notably around cycles causing memory leaks and strange behavior when passing pointers around (which is why auto_ptr isn't used all that much).  If you have something that has clear creation and deletion points and you want it to be able to be used in any way in between then there's nothing wrong with raw pointers.

Comment: I disagree categorically. C++ is powerful enough to design clear abstractions into clear classes with exception-friendly behavior buried inside, instead of exposing it to the user.

Comment: @tloach auto_ptr should not be used withcontainers. Apart this, there are no problems using smart pointers inside containers. Or just not to use pointers.

Comment: @tloach: That is some of the worst advice I have seen for C++. There is practically no need for RAW pointers in code. Any raw pointers should be wrapped and managed by an object. This is because using RAII guarantees the pointers life span (When it is wrapped (eg std::vector never ever leaks)) is correctly controlled even in the presence of exceptions (which is exceptionally hard to do correctly with RAW pointers).

Comment: @tloach: recommending not to use smart pointers because you can do it wrong in some corner case is like recommending not to use a helmet while boxing because you can still be hit in the face. In both cases, you will be less beat up if you decide to use them.

Comment: I didn't say don't use smart pointers.  I said that you need to be aware of the limitations of them and there are cases where they don't make sense.  Saying that there is one right way to do things 100% of the time in C++ is foolish.  Yes, for most jobs most of the time smart pointers are the way to go.  If you're doing OS level programming or device drivers or anything that has to be used by C code or programming for embedded devices where every cycle counts then there certainly are reasonable uses for raw pointers, and there are also ways to manage ownership to ensure things are cleaned up.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Study the **RAII idiom** (*Resource Acquisition Is Initialization*)! See e.g. the [Wikipedia article on RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

RAII is just the general idea. It is employed e.g. in the C++ standard library's [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) template classes.

---

**Very brief explanation of the RAII idiom:**

Basically, it is the C++ version of `try..finally` blocks found in some other languages. The RAII idiom is arguably more flexible.

It works like this:

- You write a wrapper class around your resource (e.g. memory). The destructor is responsible for freeing the resource.
- You create, as a local (automatic) variable, an instance of your wrapper class in a scope. Once program execution leaves that scope, the object's destructor will be called, thereby releasing the resource (e.g. memory).

**The important point is** that it doesn't matter *how* the scope is exited. Even if an exception is thrown, the scope is still exited and the wrapper object's destructor is still called.

---

**Very crude example:**

```
// BEWARE: this is NOT a good implementation at all, but is supposed to
// give you a general idea of how RAII is supposed to work:
template <typename T>
class wrapper_around
{
  public:
    wrapper_around(T value)
        : _value(value)
    { }
    T operator *()
    {
        return _value;
    }
    virtual ~wrapper_around()
    {
        delete _value;  // <-- NOTE: this is incorrect in this particular case;
                        // if T is an array type, delete[] ought to be used
    }
  private:
    T _value;
};
// ...

{
    wrapper_around<char*> heap( new char[50] );
    // ... do something ...

    // no matter how the { } scope in which heap is defined is exited,
    // if heap has a destructor, it will get called when the scope is left.
    // Therefore, delegate the responsibility of managing your allocated
    // memory to the `wrapper_around` template class.
    // there are already existing implementations that are much better
    // than the above, e.g. `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`!
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing to the concept (RAII) first and the implementation (smart pointers, whatever) then.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent though. Im pretty new to C++ and for the time being I'd rather use my own implementation instead of blindly using already-made solutions which I have no idea what they do in fact. I'll try to implement it myself firstly and then check what RAII is and how to use it properly. Thank you once again.

Comment: Fix your example so it calls delete []

Comment: @Kra: You are welcome. If you implement your own version, you will also need to think about what happens when you copy-construct (or duplicate via `=` assignment) such a wrapper object. There will be two instances that manage the same resource, but the resource must only be freed once. -- It's not beginner's stuff, but may I suggest a good book on this topic (and others) anyway: *Exceptional C++* by Herb Sutter.

Comment: @Martin York: I added a note; Yes, it should call `delete[]` in this particular case, but not in the general case. (For example, `T` could also be just `int`.) As I wrote, my intent was *not* to give a perfect implementation, but merely to show in a basic fashion how RAII is supposed to work.

Comment: @Kra: I would advise just the opposite. The earlier you get used to the available libraries the better. Note also that if you are not experienced you are prone to make mistakes in the implementation, and it will most probably be hard to debug where the problems are. If you used tested libraries you will be able to focus on your particular code problems. Later, once you get more experienced you can play implementing your own or try to understand the implementations in the libraries and the rationale for each decisions.

Comment: @Martin York, @stakx: This is why Boost has different classes for smart pointers and smart arrays.

Answer (score 9):

OK mister Java programmer:

```
try
{
    // Exception safe dynamic allocation of a block of memory.
    std::vector<char>  heap(50);

    // DO STUFF

    // Note in C++ we use stack based objects and their constructor/destructor
    // TO give a deterministic cleanup, even in the presence of exceptions.
    //
    // Look up RAII (bad name for a fantastic concept).
}
catch (...)
{
    cout << "Error, leaving function now";
    return 1;  // Though why you want to return when you have not fixed the exception is
               // slightly strange. Did you want to rethrow?
}
```

Comment: Nope I didn't want to rethrow. I have functions which return 0 when everything is fine (contains also handled exceptions in try block) and when something goes terribly wrong (like unhandled exception) function returns 1. Its up to the caller to handle the situation afterwards. Thanks for the RAII point.

Comment: @Kra: Any reason why you want to translate from exception to return value for error handling?

Answer (score 9):

The general answer is use RAII.

However, its possible to solve it by moving the variable out of the try{} scope:

```
char * heap = NULL;
try {
  heap = new char [50];
  ... stuff ...
} catch (...) {
  if (heap) {
    delete[] heap;
    heap = NULL;
  }
  ... however you want to handle the exception: rethrow, return, etc ...
}
```

Please note that I'm not recommending this as a good practice - but more of a down & dirty to be used only if you really know the risks and are still willing to take them.  Personally, I'd use RAII.

Peace

Comment: RAII: Resource Aquisition Is Initialization. RIAA is a different more evil entity. :)

Comment: I think maybe you mean RAII. I don't think getting the music industry involved will help exception safety :)

Comment: Lolls - thanks guys - obviously when I think of evil, RIAA springs to mind! ;)

Comment: `if (heap) delete[] heap;` is an anti-pattern.  It's perfectly safe to use `delete[]` on a NULL pointer, and does nothing.

Comment: You forgot to call `delete[] heap` in the `try` block.  This is why the RAII pattern is so much safer than doing this manually with `try/catch`.  Very easy to mess it up.

Comment: Yes, raw pointers are terribly problematical and shouldn't be used - RAII - preferrably by using the standard library which provides many varieties of such patterns, is preferred.

Answer (score 6):

Either move the `new` before the `try`, so that the pointer is still in scope, or use a smart pointer like `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` (in a pinch, `auto_ptr`, but it has issues) that will clean up for you on exit. Exceptions are a huge reason why smart pointers are important.

Comment: In this situation auto_ptr<> is perfect (if smart pointers were the solution). But what about other methods like a dynamic container?

Comment: Would have voted +1, if you had mentioned the general concept first: RAII. Still, nice answer.

Comment: @Martin York: You can't use `auto_ptr` with an array, can you?

Comment: Would you care to explain the issues that auto_ptr has? The auto_ptr seems well suited to this particular example.

Comment: Ah yes, that is correct. You aren't supposed to use auto_ptr because it calls `delete` instead of `delete[]`. Though some compilers will let you get away with it...not recommended practice though.

Comment: auto_ptr is perfect here.  People just auto_hate on it because they heard once that it "has issues."

Comment: boost::scoped_arr or boost::shared_arr would work for this case.

Comment: @John Dibling: auto_ptr would result in undefined behavior in this case since it uses `delete` instead of `delete[]`, as A. Levy said (and I implied earlier).

Comment: @Fred Larson: Yes std::auto_ptr like the other smart pointers mentioned will not work (without help) on dynamic arrays. My comment is based on using it in this context of this answer and not the question as a whole. If you need an array like structure you should be using some form of container (like std::vector or the new array available in tr1).

Answer (score 2):

The 'correct' answer is RAII and shared_ptr as mentioned above, but just to be complete: in your example, you could substitute

```
char *heap = new char [50];
```

with

```
char *stack = static_cast<char*>( alloca(50) );
```

`alloca` is almost identical to `malloc`, except that it alocs memory on the stack instead of the heap, so no matter how you function exits (throwing or now), the memory will be reclaimed, and no deletes or frees are necessary.

Comment: If you're going down that road, just do `char heap[50];`. The only reason to use `alloca` is if you don't know the size at compile time, and you're not too bothered about portability.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with all those that said RAII, however, I'd use Boost's [shared_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm) instead of an auto_ptr.  Auto pointer calls `delete` and not 'delete []' which will cause leaks with an array.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to declare the variable before the try block, and then just do the initialization within the block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - if you are considering the simplicity - pointer that is outer to your try block is the solution.

Regards

Answer (score -4):

Agreed with the answers on RAII and smart pointers.

However, if you insist, you can do this:

```
try { dangerous operations } 
catch { cleanup; throw; }
```

Comment: How do you clean up something that is not in scope?  Why are you re-throwing the exception?

Comment: (And you forget to clean up in case that all dangerous operations succeed.)

Comment: of course, it should be in scope. rethrowing exception is to enable us catch any exception, without killing the error information. The common pattern above is equivalent to 'finally' in SEH and in other programming languages.

Comment: So the OP asked "how does one free memory which was allocated in the try block when the exception occurs?" and you responded basically by saying "by freeing memory which was allocated in the try block when the exception occurs."  How useless.